# Mysql wrong datetime format

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, format, timestamp

I am inserting date from Android app in this format `2013-11-30T00:00:00.000+01:00` but when I see the stored data, it shows like this: `2013-11-30 00:00:00`.
I tried different structures - timestamp and datetime, it's always the same. Why is it changing, or what am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: You talk about the representation of a date. How a date is stored is something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check out the reference guide for [The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html), you'll see both `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` store the data in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

If you want to store it in the original format then you can use `CHAR` instead.